# Compare 2 columns and group the records with same value

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to compare 2 columns from the same dataframe and for where ever the match has been found I want to group the values in the 3rd column using the first value in Col1.

Below is the sample dataframe

*df*

```
  |Col1        |Col2       |cnt   |
1 |Premier     | LG Premier|3     | 
2 |LG Premier  | S Premier |3     |
3 |K Premier   | S Premier |3     |
4 |Dell        | Dell ABC  |2     |
5 |Dell ABC    | Dell GBC  |2     |
```

*Expected Output*

```
  |Col1        |Col2       |cnt   |Col3       |
1 |Premier     | LG Premier|3     |Premier    |
2 |LG Premier  | S Premier |3     |Premier    |
3 |K Premier   | S Premier |3     |Premier    |  
4 |Dell        | Dell ABC  |2     |Dell       |
5 |Dell ABC    | Dell GBC  |2     |Dell       |
```

In 1st row, Col3 assigned as Premier. 2nd row, since LG Premier found in row 1, it is also assigned as Premier, 3rd row, since S Premier found in row 2, it is also assigned as Premier.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What exactly means "standardize"? Find the largest common substring of the two items in the same row?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have changed the wording. To group matching Col1 and Col2